# Finding the turning point of a relation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, relations

I was wondering on how I can find the turning points of this relation:

$(x^2-7x+5)^2-y^2+7y-5=0$

The relation is two oval shapes that are seperated. Theres a desmos graph.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kfr2po2xxm

Thanks Braiden

Comment: What do you mean by turning points? You mean the "top and bottom" of the two ovals? If yes, then you have to implicitly differentiate this equation to find $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$, and then set it equal to $0$. Then you'll get the coordinates of the $4$ points.

Comment: @peek-a-boo how would we do it if wanted to keep it a relation?